# Can anyone help me to undestand what is $L^1((0,1))$ and $L^2((-1 , 1))$??

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I have been finding the answer from yesterday. But I have not found a single precise answer. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Don't you understand the notations or the math behind?

Comment: Notations......Can you please help me @trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L^1((0,1))$ consists of the real-valued Lebesgue integrable functions on $(0,1)$. $L^2((-1,1))$ consists of those real-valued Lebesgue measurable functions $f$ on $(-1,1)$ such that $f^2$ is Lebesgue integrable. Implicit here is that the relevant measure is the Lebesgue measure. (In some contexts these are complex-valued instead of real-valued.)

The above is not *quite* right, because we traditionally want to understand these spaces as normed spaces, but the spaces as described above are in fact pseudonormed spaces. Accordingly those are traditionally denoted as $\mathcal{L}$ spaces, and the $L$ spaces are obtained by taking equivalence classes under equality almost everywhere. But in common parlance this distinction is usually ignored, and instead statements are made about individual functions being in $L^p$, with the qualifier "almost everywhere" thrown around when necessary.

Answer (score 1):

$L^1(X)$ is the space of all real or complex funtions $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ summable (that is, Lebesgue-integrable) over $X$. In your case $X=(0,1)$. With $(0,1)$ usually it is meant the open interval on $\mathbb{R}$ whose endpoints are $0$ and $1$.

$L^2(X)$ is the space of all real or complex funtions $f: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ whose square are summable over $X$ (that is, such that every $g$ defined by $g(x)=f(x)^2$, $\forall x$ is summable over $X$) . In your case $X=(-1,1)$, the open interval on $\mathbb{R}$ whose endpoints are $-1$ and $1$.

Read the last section of the last chapter of *Introductory real analysis* by Kolmogorov and Fomin.